# How to read Oracle Apex pl/sql code snippet?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am currently working with Oracle Apex version 5.1 and I am new to Apex pl/sql code and am having a little trouble reading it.

Can anyone tell me how to read the following code?

```
l_column_value_list := apex_plugin_util.get_data2 (

    p_sql_statement  => l_region_source,

    p_min_columns    => 4,

    p_max_columns    => null,

    p_component_name => p_region.name,

    p_bind_list      => l_bind_list

    );
```

Specifically, what does "apex_plugin_util_get_data2" return? I've looked up the documentation on the function and it hasn't helped me much. Does it return the number of rows of data in the table used in the query? That's what I thought based on how "l_column_value_list" is used later in the code, but I'm doubting that now because it is labeled as 'l_COLUMN_value_list".

I got it from the code that is used to produce the Gantt chart in the Sample Charts sample application.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just a suggestion - if you're new to APEX and PL/SQL you might want to start with simpler things first before diving into APEX plugins.

Answer (score 1):

It returns a table of t_column_values indexed by column number.

"Executes the specified SQL query restricted by the provided search string (optional) and returns the values for each column. All column values are returned along with their original data types."

The "t_" is simply Oracle's naming convention for PL/SQL types. 
Package Global Variables: g_variable_name
Local Variables         : l_variable_name
**Types                   : t_type_name**

Cursors                 : c_cursor_name
Exceptions              : e_exception_name
Input Parameters        : i_parameter_name
Outut Parameters        : o_parameter_name
In/Out Parameters       : io_parameter_name

Comment: I think I understand now. Does "t" represent a variable number representing the number of columns in the table? Also, do you know how to pull the values from individual columns separately instead of pulling all of the values from all of the columns at once?